# OAuth with Google Sheets API and Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, oauth, google-sheets

I was wondering if someone could give me a direction to my problem here.
I am trying to get my Visual Studio 2012 C# Program to read off a Google Spreadsheet, and I am having no luck on how to read the cells of a spreadsheet. I looked around, and I found something called OAuth.
However, there's no solid broken down guide to follow thoroughly. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to authenticate via OAuth2, then this library was useful for me:

[OAuth2 Social Logins - Facebook, Google, Twitter, PayPal - ASP.NET MVC C# open source library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1006013/OAuth-Social-Logins-Facebook-Google-Twitter-PayPal)

However, I haven't found a method to establish a callback to my local IIS Express, so I use an external hosted ASP server.